# Group Pandas DataFrame repeated rows, preserving last index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a meaningful index and various groups of repeating rows. Suppose it looks like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])

>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  2  3  4
2  2  3  4
3  1  1  1
4  1  1  1
5  1  1  1
6  3  3  3
```

I am trying to remove the repeated rows (apart from the first one in each repeating batch), but keep the index of the last row from the batch.

The result I am looking for is this (i.e. a new "last" column containing the index of the last repeated row from the batch, which will be equal to the index if there is no repeat):

```
>>> df2
   last  a  b  c
0     0  1  1  1
1     2  2  3  4
3     5  1  1  1
6     6  3  3  3
```

Notice that the `[1, 1, 1]` entries appear twice, and are treated as separate blocks.

I have tried various combinations of `group_by`, `duplicated`, etc. but without stumbling on the necessary formulation. This feels like it should be a fairly standard thing to want to do. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this for an arbitrary DataFrame?

**Edit:**

Note that I would like to preserve the original index from the first items in the batch, and add a new column called, say, `last` for the last index from the batch.

Answer (score 3):

So in your case

```
out = df[~df.shift().ne(df).cumsum().duplicated(keep='last')]
Out[19]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
2  2  3  4
5  1  1  1
6  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this, similair to BENYs approach but using `pandas.DataFrame.diff`:

```
df[~df.diff().cumsum().duplicated(keep='last')]
```

---

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
2  2  3  4
5  1  1  1
6  3  3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BENY and @jab for your answers, which were very close to what I needed. I added the extra `last` index column with some simple tweaks as follows:

```
last_indices = df[~df.diff().cumsum().duplicated(keep='last')].index

df2 = df[~df.diff().cumsum().duplicated(keep='first')]
df2.insert(0, "last", last_indices)
```

This yields:

```
   last  a  b  c
0     0  1  1  1
1     2  2  3  4
3     5  1  1  1
6     6  3  3  3
```

**Extension:**

Although not requested in the question, a useful extension is to add a column containing the counts from each group. The following code achieves this (without relying on dense integer indexes):

```
count_groups = df.ne(df.shift()).cumsum().max(axis=1)
counts = count_groups.groupby(count_groups).agg("count")
df2.insert(1, "counts", counts.values)
```

Yielding this:

```
   last  counts  a  b  c
0     0       1  1  1  1
1     2       2  2  3  4
3     5       3  1  1  1
6     6       1  3  3  3
```